# Haxe Macro : Result an invalid access static

Tags: macros, haxe

I've encountered some problem in Haxe, and actually can't solve it. I also can't find any good doc about macros, so if you know one, I'll be thankful if you share.

Here is the code:

```
class ProfilesContainerBuilder {
#if macro
    public static function build() : ComplexType {
        var fields = new Array<Field>();
        switch (Context.getLocalType()) {
            case TInst(_, [t1]):
                fields.push({
                    name: "get",
                    access: [APublic,AStatic],
                    pos: Context.currentPos(),
                    kind: FieldType.FVar(Context.getLocalType().toComplexType(),null)
                });
                fields.push({
                    name: "profile",
                    access: [APublic,AStatic],
                    pos: Context.currentPos(),
                    kind: FieldType.FVar(t1.toComplexType(),null)
                });
                fields.push({
                    name: "_getProfile",
                    access: [],
                    pos: Context.currentPos(),
                    kind: FieldType.FFun({
                        args: [],
                        expr: { pos: Context.currentPos(), expr: EReturn(
                            macro $i{t1.getClass().name+'.fromDynamic(Json.parse(Assets.getText("profiles/"+_activeProfile+".json")))'} )},
                        params: [],
                        ret: t1.toComplexType()
                    })
                });
            default:
                Context.error("Class expected", Context.currentPos());
        }
        return TAnonymous(fields);
    }
#end
}
```

```
@:remove @:genericBuild(brocchinia.io.ressource.ProfilesContainerBuilder.build())
extern interface ProfilesContainer<T> { }
```

And after that, here is the given error, in a class that implements the built interface:

> C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/brocchinia/0,1,0/brocchinia/io/ressource/Ressource.hx:27: lines 27-114 : Invalid access static

Knowing that I access from static and local function the variable get, profile and the function `_getProfile`. Without the macro part, it works nicely.

After many hours of research, I have not found the problem, so thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the problem, I've misunderstood how `genericBuild` works, thanks to all the people who read.

Actually, the code executes a function on the type `T`, and that's impossible, that's why the error is thrown.